# Как получить значение ячейки из таблицы в sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Eсть таблица `Users`:

```
Name  |Password
---------------
User1 |  111
User3 |  333
User2 |  222
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT Password FROM Users where Name='Имя';`

дополнительная информация http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp